# C# String.Format matching a string

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out a way to match a string created with String.Format back to the original string and I'm at a loss.

So let's say I have "{0} is required" and I use it to create "Email is required" with `String.Format("{0} is required", "Email");` is there a simple way to match them if all I have is "{0} is required and "Email is required"?

My overall goal is to have a list of strings like "{0} is required", "{0} must be contain {1}" etc. and to be able to find the one that a string like "Email is required" or "Email must contain a @" could match.

For example have the following list and return the string that most closely matches:

```
"Email must contain a @"

{
"{0} is required", 
"{0} must be a {1}", 
"{0} must be between {1} and {2} characters",
"Invalid format",
}
```

So I would want "{0} is required" to be returned

Comment: Uh, can you provide some actual samples?  Are you saying you have 2 strings: `{0} is required` and `Email is required`, and you want to see if the latter is a potential match for a `String.Format`ed version of the first?  I guess you'd have to do it manually, and that sounds awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no simple way to do what you are asking. There is no inbuilt functionality to `String.Format` that preserves the format/template string. There is likely a solution to your problem, but it is one that you will have to implement yourself.

Comment: Yep.  Even regex wouldn't be 100% reliable, because even if you matched the non-replaceable parts of the string, you'd have no idea what order the tokens were in.